# How do we allow customer create product from rest api without extension?

Tags: catalog

I need customer to be able to create product without extension. I just need an access from rest api.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that customer has right to add and edit products in Magento. Yes but you can do it by creating admin role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes customer can create product using rest api in both Magento1 and Magento2.You need to create user and role for it.check magento link

https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/How-to-create-new-product-using-REST-API-in-Magento-2/td-p/49955

Comment: My products API returns products, if i try with customer i am getting error, my url : http://192.168.1.65/anusthana/api/rest/customers error : https://snag.gy/0jbhTr.jpg  can u help me @akgola